# How do I close a child menu when clicking anywhere else on the page without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a menu item that pops open a child menu when clicked. If I click it again it closes. That part works fine. My question is, without using jQuery, how can I get this child menu to close when I click anywhere else on the page?

Here is what the user clicks on:

```
<div class="main-nav" ng-click="showDialog()" ng-hide="highlightItem()">
    <a class="left" >Foo</a>
</div>
<div class="main-nav focus" ng-click="hideDialog()" ng-show="highlightItem()">
    <a class="left" >Foo</a>
</div>
```

Here is the child menu:

```
<div id="navDialog" class="main-nav-dialog" ng-show="dialog" ng-click="hideDialog()">
  <div>
      <a ui-sref="item1" class="left border-bottom">Item 1</a>
  </div>
  <div>
      <a ui-sref="item2" class="left border-bottom">Item 2</a>
  </div>
  <div>
      <a ui-sref="item3" class="left border-bottom"></i>Item 3</a>
  </div>
  <div>
      <a ui-sref="item4" class="left">Item 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is what is in my controller:

```
var show = false;
$scope.showDialog = function() {
  if (show === false) {
      show = true;
      $scope.dialog = true;
      return show;
  }
};
$scope.hideDialog = function() {
  if (show === true) {
      show = false;
      $scope.dialog = false
      return show;
  }
};
$scope.highlightItem = function() {
  return show;
};
```

Comment: You would probably want to make a directive and then use angular.element to get the parent('body').bind('click', doStuff).  Do not forget to scope.$on('$destroy', unBindMyListeners)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to attach to the body a click listener when you show your dialog is shown and then remove that listener when the dialog is closed (by selecting an item on the dialog or selecting elsewhere on the screen/the body). Here is some pseudocode.

```
var handleDialogClose = function() {
  //remove event listener handleDialogClose from body tag
  //Close dialog
}

var handleDialogItemClicked = function() {
  handleDialogClose();
  //Do some other work
}

var handleDialogOpen = function() {
  // add event listener handleDialogClose to body tag
  // Show dialog
}
```

Also, this would be much easier to do with jQuery, so you should consider using that in your project. AngularJS and jQuery work wonderfully together!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest fix is to make use of the event bubbling effect.
Since events bubble to the top of dom tree meaning that any click event fired by a child dom element will keep on firing on all parent nodes till it reaches the top of the document "if it didn't get suppressed while bubbling to the top". 
So basically what you want to do is if any click reaches the body tag it automatically closes all the child menus ! but that would kill the child menu that was just recently opened. To avoid that you just stop the bubbling of the click event on the child menus themselves !

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function hideAll() {
            $("child-one").style.display = "none";
            $("child-two").style.display = "none";
        }

        function show(event, theDiv) {
            theDiv.style.display = "block";
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onclick="hideAll();">
    <div id="child-one" onclick="show(event,this);">
        first child
    </div>
    <div id="child-two" onclick="show(event,this);">
        second child
    </div>
</body>
```

you can read more about event bubbling effect here: 
http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

and about the stopPropagation method here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple fiddle that can be tweaked to suit your needs: jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/1516/